# Not able to restore NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nuget, nuget-package-restore

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       NuGet Package restore failed for project EncoreTix: Unable to find version '3.3.0' of package 'Castle.Windsor'..            0\
```

[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfE60.jpg)

Tried restoring it, deleting the folder and restore it. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Tried manual install via `Install-Package Castle.Windsor` ?

Comment: Any additional information on the Output pane?

Comment: Are you using a vpn or proxy?  Or did you perhaps remove public nuget from your sources?

Comment: Since more than one package seems to have this problem: could it be that another nuget package tries to install the not restorable packages? In this case I'd also recommend looking into the nuspec file of the installed package

Comment: I've had this problem, as well, and it wasn't resolved until I enabled NuGet Package restore and restarted visual studio.